# NoSuchMethod exception observed when I tried to access private method from third party jar

Tags: java, reflection

I have some private method inside a jar file due to some restriction of visibility to outer class. I just added that jar file through maven dependency. And I want to call that private method and return the value after invoke. but when I tried to execute below code throws NoSuchMethod Exception.

**Code:**

```
  Method method = BankFlowTestExecutor.class.getDeclaredMethod("executeBatchCommand", String.class);
  method.setAccessible(true);
```

The exception observed as soon as its executed the first line in the above code.

**Exception:**

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:
>   com.paypal.test.BankFlowTestExecutor.executeBatchCommand(java.lang.String)  at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:2130)

Also, I used Method[] to get all the methods in the class but it returns only public method not private methods which is in the class.

Any leads?

Comment: Is the method there in the version you're using? If yes, how is it declared in `BankFlowTestExecutor`?

Comment: You can try list all methods to make sure that method is there. Also check parameters type.

Comment: Cross check that the jar file contains exactly that method. Then ensure you put up a [mcve] here. Meaning: give the code that selects the method, and the exact method signature.

Comment: the error is trying to say that method doesn't exist. Can you check that the method is there or not .

Comment: ernest - Its private data access specifier. And its overloaded method in that class which has obj return type

Comment: Being private shouldn't be a problem, since that is not part of method signature. Are you sure that this method is declared in that class? How do you know it?

Comment: I just imported tat repository in my local with same version that I mentioned in pom.xml. Also, Its not returning any of the private method in the class except public

Comment: "I used Method[] to get all the methods in the class but it returns only public method not private methods which is in the class." you probably used `getMethods()` which works only for public methods (including inherited ones). You need `getDeclaredMethods()` to get all methods declared in current class (including private ones).

Comment: I used getDeclaredMethods(). I didn't use getMethods()

Comment: According to the docs, the second argument for getDeclaredMethod() is: the parameterTypes parameter is an array of Class objects that identify the method's formal parameter types, in declared order. Is that what String.class does for your method?

Comment: If `getDeclaredMethods()` doesn't include method you are looking for then either there is no such method in class, or that there is bug in Java. More probable version IMO is lack of method in class (unless you are using some non-standard Java implementation which contains such buggy behavior).

Comment: String obj is the arg that used for that method for getDeclatedMethod()

Comment: Is it possible that method you are trying to find is declared in nested class? Like `class BankFlowTestExecutor{ .. class SomeNestedClass{ .. private void executeBatchCommand(String cmd){...} } }`? In that scenario `getDeclaredMethod` wouldn't be able to find it in `BankFlowTestExecutor` because it wasn't declared in it, but in `BankFlowTestExecutor.SomeNestedClass`.

Comment: NO. The bankFlowTestExecutor is not inherited. Its independent class file which has private and non-private access specifier methods.

Comment: I think reflection will work only for the class in same package. Since Its third party jar , and failed to fetch private data members. Its my assumption.

Comment: Another possibility is that you have two `BankFlowTestExecutor` classes and you are using one which doesn't have that method. Did you create in your project such class? Or even have it in same package structure in your project as one from JAR?

Comment: It's from JAR and the same repo I cloned local and Imported into eclipse.